# Setting navigation between different screens on my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello stackoverflow i develop app in react-native and I completely implement login system. Now my problem is I don't understand how I route between different screens like i have flows e.g signup flow :
1)user enter phone number (verifyPhone screen)
2)user enter confirmation code and enter his data e.g username email etc(verify code screen)
3)user enter login credentials (loginScreen)
4)then user navigate to home screen

i have 4 different flows like signup,signin,signout,forgotpassword

I don't know how I achieve the functionality i try to do it through stacknavigator and switchnavigator but nothing works

my app.js look like :

```js
//app.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator, Platform } from 'react-native';
import {createAppContainer,createStackNavigator,createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import MobileCheck from './screens/MobileCheck';
import VerifyCode from './screens/VerifyCode';
import SignUp from './screens/SignUp';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import ForgotPassword from './screens/ForgotPassword';
//import helper from './helper';


// const authSwitch = createSwitchNavigator ({
//   Home: HomeScreen,
//   stack :  createStackNavigator({
//     MobileCheck : MobileCheck,
//     VerifyCode : VerifyCode,
//     SignUp : SignUp,
//   })



// })
const authSwitch = createStackNavigator({
//   MobileCheck : {
//     screen : MobileCheck
//   },
//   VerifyCode : {
//     screen : VerifyCode
//   },
//  SignUp : {
//     screen : SignUp
//   },
  Login : {
    screen : LoginScreen
  },
  Home : {
    screen : HomeScreen
  },
//   SignUp : {
//     screen : SignUp
//   },
//   MobileCheck : {
//     screen : MobileCheck
//   },
//   VerifyCode : {
//     screen : VerifyCode
//   },
//   ForgotPassword : {
//     screen : ForgotPassword
//   },
    // Help : {
    //     screen : helper
    // },
})
const App = createAppContainer(authSwitch);

// const SignUpStack = createStackNavigator({

// })
// const LoginStack = createStackNavigator({

// })
// const ForgotPasswordStack = createStackNavigator({

// })
// const App = createSwitchNavigator({
  
// })
export default App;
```

Comment: Guessing you may need some design pattern which is built based on `status machine` method

Comment: Where does PHP and MySQL come in?

Comment: Also, you've posted way too much code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to remove anything that's not relevant to the issue (including all css and code that's commented out)

Comment: **Welcome**. Please remove all unwanted...and make a very minimal code which demonstrated your issue. Add data structure, sample data and your required output. And you will get the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hey Haseeb Javaid**

It seems you are using latest **react-navigation version 5+** 
So as per their documentation, you have to create your StackNavigator something like this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For more information, you can follow this [react-navigation documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html)

Hope it will help you :)

**Thanks!**